# How can I use a local DNS server?

Tags: 12.04, networking, dns, hosts, resolvconf

I need to test a few websites on my local network.

I've already setup a DNS server with bind9 for my internet domains, and that works.

I can also add a few domains to the /etc/hosts file, so I can test various sites with virtual name based hosting on the local machine.

Now, I've to test various browsers, which means I will be on various machines (e.g. Windows for IE testing).

I don't want to always have to edit the hosts file on these machines.
I want to use the dns server to centrally administer the domains, and just put the DNS server into each machines' config.

How can I add this DNS server to my Ubuntu 12.04 machine, so the lookup order goes like this:

- hosts file
- MY dns-server
- ISP dns-server

What I want to do is add www.something.tld or  to the DNS-server, and then be able to test these domains from every computer in the local network that uses this dns server (windows, linux).

The thing is, I don't have www.something.tld registered, this is just for testing purposes. To make sure everything really works.

Basically, I want to resolve a custom domain name or host name to a 192.168.1.x address.

Where do I have to put my DNS server for that ?

Answer (score 0):

The way to achieve this is to configure your NS appropriately - your clients know only about your (own) default NS.

Every name server can be configured to "forward" inquiries it cannot answer to some other NS. For example (taken from http://www.akadia.com/services/howto_forward_dns.html), I omitted the `forward first` statement, as you don't want that.

```
options {
  ...

  forwarders {
    193.247.122.26;
  };
  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will help you, but it worked for me for what seems to be a very similar situation. I am running a headless Raspberry Pi and wanted to log in using a name rather than an IP address.
On my router (192.168.1.1), I first set the IP of the RPi as Static. Next, I went to the setting for *Static NAT* in the *Firewall* section. Here there is a table with fields for "Networked Computer/Device" and for "Public IP Address". I set the RPi's name to correspond to the static IP address I had already set.
In order to make sure the NAT would happen, I checked that all my computers' network settings had 192.168.1.1 as the first DNS server. (It may already be set that way by default.) I am using mostly OSX--the DNS setting can be found in *Network* in System Preferences--click the "Advanced" button and select the "DNS" tab.
My router is for Verizon FiOS (Westell A90-9100EM15).